# How do I find the sum of values for a multidimensional array and replace values of unused indexes?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I have 4x4 2D array that already has values in each index. I want to have a function that calculates the sum of a row/column of the array and store it at the first/final column and have the other indexes revert to 0.

This is what I have to render my array:

```
public static void print2Darray(int[][] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i][j]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Which displays something like this:

```
10  15  30  40  
15  5   8   2   
20  2   4   2   
1   4   5   0
```

Currently this is the function that I have:

```
public static void sumLeft(int[][] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i][0] = (numbers[i][0] + numbers[i][1] + numbers[i][2] + numbers[i][3]);
        if (i == 3) {
            numbers[0][1] = 0;
            numbers[0][2] = 0;
            numbers[0][3] = 0;
            numbers[1][1] = 0;
            numbers[1][2] = 0;
            numbers[1][3] = 0;
            numbers[2][1] = 0;
            numbers[2][2] = 0;
            numbers[2][3] = 0;
            numbers[3][1] = 0;
            numbers[3][2] = 0;
            numbers[3][3] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Which does this:

```
95  0   0   0   
30  0   0   0   
28  0   0   0   
10  0   0   0
```

I just want to find an algorithm that would do this without "cheating" or just hacking my way through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is loop over the elements of the "row" array:

```
public static void sumLeft(int[][] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
            numbers[i][0] += numbers[i][j];
            numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i++` vs `++j`? Sure they do the same, but consistency is a good thing in programming *(in my opinion, at least)*.

Comment: Looks like two people think in that way and one in another. 2 vs 1.

Comment: Ahhh yes, muscle memory! Hard to break. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the inner loop in the reverse order as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { // for all rows
    int sum = 0; // about to be sum, reset every row
    for (int j = numbers[i].length -1 ; j >=0; j--) { // iterate reverse in columns
        if (j == 0) {
            numbers[i][j] += sum; // final sum
        } else {
            sum += numbers[i][j]; // keep evaluating
            numbers[i][j] = 0; //reset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `numbers[i][0] += sum; // final sum`?

Comment: @Andreas the check is already there.`j==0` and yes it would be a +=

Answer (score 2):

Why did not you do simple this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
        numbers[i][0] += numbers[i][j];
        numbers[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```